# Success/failure of linux command executed inside system command in C

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to execute a linux tar command inside a C system() function. It goes like this :

```
if (-1 == system("tar -xf files.tar.gz file1")) {
    printf("tar failed\n");
}
```

If there is no "file1" inside "files.tar.gz", the program doesn't print "tar failed". How do I identify if the command executed inside system() has failed?

Comment: AFAIK, `system()` returns -1 on it's _own_ failure (ex. fail to `fork()`), not for the _command_ failure.

Comment: On Linux a non-zero exit status is typically taken to be an error.

Comment: the return is not -1 : see [tar return codes](http://news-posts.aplawrence.com/2073.html). or just run it on the command line and check $?

Answer (score 3):

From [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/):

> If command is not a null pointer, the value returned depends on the
>   system and library implementations, but it is generally expected to be
>   the status code returned by the called command, if supported.

On Linux, programs typically return a zero exit status on success and another value on failure.  Instead of checking the particular exit status `-1` you could try checking non-zero:

```
if (system("echo hi"))
    printf("In C a non-zero value is treated as true\n");
```

When I run `tar` on my system with a valid input file I can check the return status by:

```
# echo With a valid input file
# tar -cf test.tar test.py
# echo $?
0
# echo with an invalid input file
# tar -cf test.tar t
tar: t: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
# echo $?
2
```

Here `tar` returns an exit status of `2` on failure.

With the following program I can print the error status:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  printf("%i\n", system("tar -cf test.tar test.py"));   /// Outputs 0
  printf("%i\n", system("tar -cf test.tar bad"));   /// Outputs 512

  int err;
  if ((err = system("tar -cf test.tar test.py")))
  {
      printf("There was an error (%i)\n", err);
      return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The one that outputs `0` succeeded while the other failed.  I don't known why the error status is different when I call `tar` from bash and my C program.

Comment: Thanks but how do I detect that in the C program?

Comment: The the reason that error status differs from what you see in the shell is documented in the `system()` manual page: "The value returned is -1 on error (e.g., `fork(2)` failed), and the return status of the command otherwise.  This latter return status is in the format specified in `wait(2)`.  **Thus, the exit code of the command will  be  `WEXITSTATUS(status)`.**"

Answer (score 0):

system(cmdline) returns -1 if it fails to call cmd, if it does it also sets errno.

if system succeeds, it returns the return char of the last
cmd, executed as part of the cmdline.